systemd-logind.service fails on centos 9
systemd-logind.service is failing on CentOS 9 hosted on a container. Previously, on CentOS 8, it used to run without any issues.
systemctl list-units --failed
  UNIT                   LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
 systemd-logind.service loaded failed failed User Login Management

systemd[1]: Stopped User Login Management.
systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start User Login Management.

When triggering a restart through systemctl restart systemd-logind.service, it enters the running state. Is there any workaround to fix it so that it runs by default?
